# Compact embedding of the $\mathcal{C}^k$ norm on a compact Kahler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a smooth complex valued function $f$ on a Kahler manifold $X$, we can define its $\mathcal{C}^k$ norm to be $\sum_{p+q \leq k, 0 \leq p \leq q} sup_{X}|\nabla^{p} \overline{\nabla^q} f|_g$, where in local coordinates $|\nabla^{p} \overline{\nabla^q} f|^2_g = g^{i_1\bar k_1} \ldots g^{l_q \bar j_q}\partial_{i_1} \ldots \partial_{i_p}\partial_{\bar j_1} \ldots \partial_{\bar j_q}f\partial_{l_1} \ldots \partial_{l_q}\partial_{\bar k_1} \ldots \partial_{\bar k_p}f$.

I was told that there is an inclusion from $\mathcal{C}^{k+1} \to \mathcal{C}^k$ and it is compact. I suppose that I first need to show that if the $\mathcal{C}^{k+1}$ norm of $f$ is bounded by a multiple(independent of $f$) of its $\mathcal{C^k}$ norm. I am not sure how I should do that. My guess is that some kind of integration by part is needed here to "decrease the partials".

Comment: Is this not (equivalent to) the standard $C^k$ norm (at least locally, in charts)? If so, this is just the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: May I ask what $C^k$ norm are you referring to？Perhaps any reference so I can look it up?

Comment: Here's a version that gives what I claim. Suppose $X$ is compact and let $\theta_1,\dotsc,\theta_N$ be a partition of unity relative to some system of charts that covers $X$. Then define $$\|u\|_{C^k}=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}\sup_X |D^\alpha(\theta_i u)|,$$ where $D^\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th multiderivative in the chart associated to $\theta_i$. This norm should be equivalent (in the sense of norms) to what you wrote. It has the desired compactness property, so your norm does too.

Comment: I see. Is there any reference on it?

Comment: This is a standard exercise in advanced calculus. You apply the Arzela-Ascoli theorem to the sequence and its derivatives. The main ideas are in Chapter 5 of Jost's postmodern analysis book.

Comment: I see, just one more clarification: This is actually just a seminorm, then how do you make sense of the compact embedding? The way I see it is that  the Heine-Borel property of this Frechet space would give us something that is similar to a "compact embedding".

Comment: The OP says $p,q\ge 0$ which includes $p=q=0$, i.e. the sup norm of $f$ itself. So this is a norm.

Comment: This space definitely does not have a Heine-Borel property. The point is that you get compactness in a weaker topology given boundedness in a stronger topology.